# How to concatenate two web.xml?

Tags: java, xml, web-applications, ant

I have Java project with different modules on it. The project have one core module where all the common configuration files kept. Each module has separate configuration files like `.properties` files, `hibernate.cfg`, `web.xml` etc. It is not necessary that every time all modules will be there on the final build.

My problem is that, suppose 3 modules such as A, B & C are present. Each has its on `web.xml` and it contains only the servlets and mapping necessary for that. I want to know how concatenate these `web.xml` while building. I know that from `ant` I can call a Java application. The position of tags is important in `web.xml`.

How it possible to concatenate these `web.xml` effectively? I tried xstream for this but it was a failure.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an Servlet 3.0 container, then only your core module would have a `web.xml` and your other modules would each provide their own [`web-fragment.xml`](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment).

Comment: unfortunately my employer doesn't want me to migrate to servlet 3 right now

Comment: any documentation on how to use this edward?

Answer (score 1):

There are following ways you can achieve this:

1. using xstream marshalling for your purpose; see the [question on marshalling of `Map`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6825271/1523910) for how to marshal an object. or use the [official](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html) tutorial
2. Use a SAX Parsing, by manually converting it.
3. Convert the whole XML to a JSON using [`JSON.org`](http://www.json.org/) and merge each of the XMLs and rebuild the XML from the JSON. **NOTE**: the don't use the `xstream` for this purpose, it reverses the whole XML, causing validation errors to the resulting XMLs.

Answer (score 0):

Your quesion itself has answer , Write a small java program to parse all XML you want to combine , get required nodeList , write in new XML in the order you want.
Call this java program during Ant build.

Comment: Do you have an example code or link where I can start doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/index.html) is great for xmlprocessing with ant.
See details and examples here :
xmltask :
[xml task manual](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/index.html)
[xml manipulation using xml task](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/11/01/xml-manipulation-using-xmltask.html)
useful xpath links :
http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/